# Output multidimensional array to list

Tags: php

Can anyone help output a multidimensional array, please.

Not to sure where I have gone wrong.
The sort ordering looks correct, but its not displaying the results.

```
<?php
$atest = Array ( "0" => Array ( "id" => "913", "testname" => "qwerty1", "i" => "1" ),
                 "1" => Array ( "id" => "913", "testname" => "test22", "i" => "2" ),
                 "2" => Array ( "id" => "913", "testname" => "American1", "i" => "3" ),
                 "3" => Array ( "id" => "913", "testname" => "Eagle4", "i" => "4" ) );

$range = range('A','Z');
$output = array();
$output['#'] = array();

foreach($range as $letter){
    $output[$letter] = array();
}

foreach($atest as $test){
    if ($test["testname"] !='') {

        $uc = ucfirst($test["testname"]);
        if(array_search($uc[0], $range) === FALSE){
            $output['#'][] = $uc;
        } else {
            $output[$uc[0]][] = $uc;
        }

    }
}

foreach($output AS $letter => $result){
    echo $letter . "<br/>--------<br/>\n";
    sort($result);
    foreach($result AS $indresult){
        echo '<a href="index.php?option=com_comprofiler&task=page&user=' . (int) $indresult['id'] . '&b=' . $indresult['i'] . '">' . $indresult['testname'] . '</a><br/>';
    }
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'id' on line 32` etc. etc. : http://codepad.viper-7.com/w4Mpza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not putting the whole sub-array into `$output`, you're only putting `$uc`. Change the middle `foreach` loop to:

```
foreach($atest as $test){
    if ($test["testname"] !='') {

        $uc = ucfirst($test["testname"]);
        if(array_search($uc[0], $range) === FALSE){
            $output['#'][] = $test;
        } else {
            $output[$uc[0]][] = $test;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `print_r` function, for example for array dump:

```
print_r($atest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $output[$uc[0]][] = $test;
```

instead of

`$output[$uc[0]][] = $uc;` // only the name is stored.

See demo [here](https://eval.in/100478)